# How to navigate a website using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, navigation, google-plus

I have seen that navigation in Google+ isn't normal navigation as in other sites. Many elements remain the same, and I am sure it isn't a 
**$('body').load()** 
or something like that because the page actually reloads and the URL changes.

Can anyone explain to me how it's done?

Comment: Haven't you just asked the same question? It was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It is using AJAX. And with that, it is also using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

The History API allows you to control the history of the browser, changing the URLs to change the state of the website. Each state is a different URL. The only drawback is that it's not supported on older browsers, on which it fallbacks usings hashbangs (it appends `#foo/bar` to the URL).

So it uses some kind of `$('body').load()`, except it doesn't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve this you need ajax/Jquery usually.

```
$('#randomdiv').load('load.php');
```

This loads load.php generated html in div randomdiv